# powershell IE automation href issue

Tags: html, powershell, automation

I am trying to access Jtrac webpage using powershell. i am able to login into but i am unable to access SEARCH button which href link.

```
$Url = “http://kbserver/workflow/app/login”
enter code here`$Username=”XXXXX”
enter code here`$Password=”XXXXX”
$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$IE.visible = $true;
$IE.navigate($Url);
while ($IE.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000; 
} 
$Login = $IE.document.getElementById("loginName3").value = "$Username" 
$Login = $IE.Document.getElementById(“password12”).value= "$Password" 
$Login = $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | where-object   {$_.type -eq "submit"}
$Login.click();
while ($IE.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 5000; 
} 
$Login = $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | where {$_.href -eq "'?wicket:interface=:2:table:dashboardRows:3:dashboardRow:search::ILinkListen     er::'"}
$Login.click();
```

Error which i am getting is

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Dinesh\Webbb.ps1:20 char:13
+ $Login.click <<<< ();
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (click:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

```html
<a href="?wicket:interface=:2:table:dashboardRows:3:dashboardRow:search::ILinkListener::">
<img title="SEARCH" src="../resources/search.gif"> </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a typo in line 19, `ILinkListen     er::` at the end of your where instead of  `ILinkListener::`. Where isn't finding anything to match, so it returns null, and that's how you get your null-valued $Login object.

Edit: Your problem is still line 19, you should print out  `$IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")` and verify that it's actually returning what you expect, because your `where` filter is not matching anything and returning $null to $Login.

Edit2: went to a website and grabbed all the hrefs and took a look, powershell removes the "" from the hrefs.

you should have `$IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | where {$_.href -eq "?wicket:interface=:2:table:dashboardRows:3:dashboardRow:search::ILinkListener::"}` instead.

Edit 3: Your second issue can be solved with regex using the `-match` operator instead of -eq (-eq does not really work if the item you are checking is dyanmic ).

Like this:

`$IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | where {$_.href -match "\?wicket:interface=:\d"}`

This regex will return anything that containts "?wicket:interface=:digit".
One digit is the best option here since it will keep growing on refresh,  assuming nothing else on the page matches that this should be good.

Comment: Could you post the output of $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") ?

Comment: Write-Host $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")                                                        mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass mshtml.HTMLAnchorElementClass                 like this i have more no of lines...

Comment: Write-Host will only give you the class name, just call it like this: 
$IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | select href

Comment: This is what i m getting                                                              http://kbserver/workflow/app/?wicket:interface=:2:table:dashboardRows:3:dashboardRow:search::ILinkListener::

Comment: $Login = $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | where-object {$_.href -eq "http://kbserver/workflow/app/?wicket:interface=:2:table:dashboardRows:3:dashboardRow:search::ILinkListener::"}
$Login.Click() 

  So i tried like this  still the same error                  PS C:\Users\Dinesh> .\Webbb.ps1
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\Dinesh\Webbb.ps1:20 char:13
+ $Login.Click <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Click:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: $Login = $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | where-object {$_.href -eq "http://kbserver/workflow/app/?wicket:interface=:2:table:dashboardRows:3:dashboardRow:search::ILinkListener::"}
$Login.Click()             Now its working....

Comment: I m facing new issue here... each time number 57{wicket:interface=:57} gets changed thrice. If i am refresh again im getting as 60.                                                                                                                                 http://kbserver/workflow/app/?wicket:interface=:57:table:dashboardRows:3:dashboardRow:search::ILinkListener::                    How to handle this, any way to ignore this

Comment: Updated with a regex matching based solution.